# Case study: Is this an effective way to split a file?

Tags: java, file-io, split

So om working my way trough a task in my java-course at school. For better understanding of what the code is supposed to do ill quote it:

"(Split files) Suppose you want to back up a huge file(e.g., a 10-GB AVI file) to a CD-R. You can achieve it by splitting the file into smaller pieces and backing up these pieces separately. Write a utility program that splits a large file into smaller ones using the following command: **java** ***ClassName*** ***SourceFile*** ***numberOfPieces***

The command creates the files ***SourceFile.1***, ***SourceFile2***...etc

Now to be clear. This post is in no way an attempt to get a "solution" for the problem. I have solved it (with what i  know). And i merely want to get more enlightned on some matters that crossed my mind when writing the code.

1. Is it neccesary to create a new output for every single file im
   copying to? Doesn`t  this demand unneccesary system power?
2. The first file that gets copied(SourceFile is in this case a .png
   file) is possible to view. And show a fraction of the original
   picture. *(If i split into two. i can view half the picture.)* But
   the latter ones i cant view.. Why is that?
3. Is it possible to reassemble the splitted files in any way? if my
   pictures was split into two files, can i put them back together and
   view the whole picture?

The code, if you want to look at it.

All feedback is welcome,
Have a good day! :)

```
package oblig2;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

/**
 * Main method
 * 
 * @param args[0] for source file          
 * @param args[1] for number of pieces           
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // The program needs to be executed with two parameters in order to
    // work. This sentence check for it.
    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.out.println("Usage: java Copy sourceFile numberOfPieces");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    // Check whether or not the sourcefile exists
    File sourceFile = new File(args[0]);
    if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Source file " + args[0] + " does not exist");
        System.exit(2);
    }
    // Need an Array to store all the new files that is supposed to contain
    // parts of the original file
    ArrayList<File> fileArray = new ArrayList<File>();

    // All the new files need their own output(or do they?)
    ArrayList<BufferedOutputStream> outputArray = new ArrayList<BufferedOutputStream>();

    // Using randomAccessFile on the sourcefile to easier read parts of it
    RandomAccessFile inOutSourceFile = new RandomAccessFile(sourceFile,
            "rw");

    // This loop changes the name for the new files, so they match the
    // sourcefile with an appended digit
    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(args[1]); i++) {
        String nameAppender = String.valueOf(i);
        String nameBuilder;
        int suffix = args[0].indexOf(".");
        nameBuilder = args[0].substring(0, suffix);
        fileArray.add((new File(nameBuilder + nameAppender + ".dat")));
    }

    // Here i create the output needed for all the new files
    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(args[1]); i++) {
        outputArray.add(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                new File(fileArray.get(i).getAbsolutePath()))));
    }

    // Now i determine in how many parts the sourcefile needs to be split,
    // and the size of each.
    float size = inOutSourceFile.length();
    double parts = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    double partSize = size / parts;
    int r, numberOfBytesCopied = 0;


    // This loop actually does the job of copying the parts into the new
    // files
    for (int i = 1; i <= parts; i++) {
        while (inOutSourceFile.getFilePointer() < partSize * i) {
            r = inOutSourceFile.readByte();
            outputArray.get(i - 1).write((byte) r);
            numberOfBytesCopied++;
        }

    }
    // Here i close the input and outputs
    inOutSourceFile.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
        outputArray.get(i).close();
    }

    // Display the operations
    System.out.println(args[0] + " Has been split into " + args[1]
            + " pieces. " + "\n" + "Each file containig " + partSize
            + " Bytes each.");

}

}
```

Comment: uhm, to merge the file i would create a new file "final_fine.x" and put inside it the bytes from all parts (something like file_part1.originalformat, file_part2.originalformat) etc.

Comment: Yeah, but i wonder if the file will be changed in any way. I should test this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Of course it is necessary to open all output files. But you don't have to open them at all times. You can open the first file, write to it, close it, open the second file, write to it, close it, etc.
2. File format, .png for example, have a structure that have to follow. It may have special header, and may have special footer. That's why when this file split into two or more, the first will lose its footer, the middle will lose its header and footer, and the last will lose it's header. This make them unusable as individual file.
3. Of course it is possible. By combining back all the parts, the original file fill be restructured.

Comment: It would have been wonderfull if i could use one "FileOutput" and just changed the files it writes to underway. Instead of creating a new one. I added your suggestion to my code. it now closes the outputs immideatly after its done. But i didnt notice and speed improvement thou.